# Is there a custom FxCop rule that will detect unused PUBLIC methods?

Tags: .net, code-analysis, fxcop, public-method

I just tried FxCop.  It does detect unused private methods, but not unused public.  Is there a custom rule that I can download, plug-in that will detect public methods that aren't called from within the same assembly?

Answer (score 15):

Corey, my answer of using FxCop had assumed you were interested in removing unused private members, however to solve the problem with other cases you can try using [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). Here is some CQL to detect unused public members (adapted from an article listed below):

```
// <Name>Potentially unused methods</Name>
WARN IF Count > 0 IN SELECT METHODS WHERE
 MethodCa == 0 AND            // Ca=0 -> No Afferent Coupling -> The method 
                              // is not used in the context of this
                              // application.

 IsPublic AND                 // Check for unused public methods

 !IsEntryPoint AND            // Main() method is not used by-design.

 !IsExplicitInterfaceImpl AND // The IL code never explicitely calls 
                              // explicit interface methods implementation.

 !IsClassConstructor AND      // The IL code never explicitely calls class
                              // constructors.

 !IsFinalizer                 // The IL code never explicitely calls
                              // finalizers.
```

Source: [Patrick Smacchia's "Code metrics on Coupling, Dead Code, Design flaws and Re-engineering](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/02/15/code-metrics-on-coupling-dead-code-design-flaws-and-re-engineering.aspx). The article also goes over detecting dead fields and types.

*(EDIT: made answer more understandable)*

---

EDIT 11th June 2012: *Explain new NDepend facilities concerning unused code. Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of this tool.*

Since NDepend v4 released in May 2012, the tool proposes to write [Code Rule over LINQ Query (CQLinq)](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/02/15/code-metrics-on-coupling-dead-code-design-flaws-and-re-engineering.aspx). Around [200 default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed, 3 of them being dedicated to *unused/dead code* detection:

- [Potentially dead Types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Types.html) (hence detect unused class, struct, interface, delegate...)
- **[Potentially dead Methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Methods.html)** (hence detect unused method, ctor, property getter/setter...)
- [Potentially dead Fields](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Fields.html)

These CQLinq code rules are more powerful than the previous CQL ones. If you click these 3 links above toward the source code of these rules, you'll see that the ones concerning types and methods are a bit complex. This is because they detect not only unused types and methods, but also types and methods used *only* by unused dead types and methods (recursive).

This is *static analysis*, hence the prefix *Potentially* in the rule names. If a code element is used *only* through reflection, these rules might consider it as unused which is not the case.

In addition to using these 3 rules, I'd advise measuring code coverage by tests and striving for having full coverage. Often, you'll see that code that cannot be covered by tests, is actually *unused/dead* code that can be safely discarded. This is especially useful in complex algorithms where it is not clear if a branch of code is reachable or not.

Answer (score 8):

If a method is unused and public FxCop assumes that you have made it public for external things to access.

If unused public methods lead to FxCop warnings writing APIs and the like would be a pain - you'd get loads of FxCop warnings for methods you intend others to use.

If you don't need anything external to access your assembly/exe consider find-replacing `public` with `internal`. Your application will run the same and FxCop will be able to find the unreferenced internal methods.

If you do need external access find which methods are really needed to be external, and make all the rest internal.

Any methods you make externally visible could have unit tests too.

Answer (score 3):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is your friend for this kind of thing

Comment: NDepend is awesome, but I don't see how it can detect unused public methods.

Comment: @Ian Nelson: I responded below with how to use NDepend to search for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

How would it know that the public methods are unused?

By marking a method as public it can be accessed by any application which references your library.

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer.  I'm just interested in my one assembly, an exe, by the way, not a dll.