# VS2008 - How do I automate Edit.FindAllReferences methods in my source files?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to find all unused references in my source files, like unused properties, methods and constants. I hope to incorporate this into my daily build.
I do not use reflection in my project so this means that if a property has 0 references, I can safely remove it.
The only clue I've got so far is that I need to write some macro to run DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FindAllReferences")
but how do I proceed from there? And is it possible to do all these without using a macro? Ideally it should run from a command line program.
Thank you.

Comment: possibly the easiest way is buy a ReSharper license ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71518/is-there-a-custom-fxcop-rule-that-will-detect-unused-public-methods) (*Is there a custom FxCop rule that will detect unused PUBLIC methods?*)

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll try out NDepend. This is the first time I'm hearing about it.