# Find uncalled code

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tools and techniques do you use to find dead code in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162641/what-tools-and-techniques-do-you-use-to-find-dead-code-in-net)

Does anyone know of a tool that can find functions that are not being called?

Clarification: functions that are not being called by anything in the solution. Should not matter if they are public, private etc.

Comment: This question needs clarification: "not being called"... do you mean private methods in a class not being called by any other methods in the class? Or do you mean which public methods in your whole solution  are not being used elsewhere in your application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several tools available which will do this to varying degrees of depth.

- Resharper
- NCover
- FxCop

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper will identify private or internal methods that are not called.

Answer (score 1):

NCover will give you all kinds of code coverage goodness, however I believe it's a bit expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [FxCop](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=917023F6-D5B7-41BB-BBC0-411A7D66CF3C) can do that for you.

Comment: Only for private members, although here is a good discussion about how it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71518/is-there-a-custom-fxcop-rule-that-will-detect-unused-public-methods

Answer (score 0):

try ncover, its good tool which helps in refactoring a lot

Answer (score 0):

i myself hate Resharper because their many thing goes wrong in Resharper. you need to use telerik customization it can be better then resharper.