# What tools and techniques do you use to find dead code?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, code-analysis

What tools and techniques do you use to find dead code in .NET?

In the past, I've decorated methods with the Obsolete attribute (passing true so the compiler will issue an error, as described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664623.aspx)).

I'd be interested in seeing the suggestions of others (beyond tools like FxCop or ReSharper). I want to make sure I'm not missing out on other tools that would be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool for finding unreferenced functions (dead, obsolete code) in a C# app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585/is-there-a-tool-for-finding-unreferenced-functions-dead-obsolete-code-in-a-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413548/visual-studio-find-unused-code/1413573#1413573

Comment: A question asked 5 years ago can't be a duplicate of a question asked 4 years ago.

Comment: The tools part of the question would be on-topic at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TDD + NCover

Comment: But what if you have a unit test for an otherwise unused method?

Answer (score 16):

Why do you need other answers? FxCop and Resharper do the trick, especially seeing as FxCop is now integrated into VS through "Code Analysis".

Comment: Code Analysis in visual studio is just the same as running FxCop manually?

Comment: @Svish; Yes, they are the same.

Answer (score 4):

it appears gray in ReSharper if it's dead code (at least within the solution only)...like uncalled methods or classes or unused properties and variables

Answer (score 2):

Once again, I recommend [AQTime](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/application-performance-profiling). The static code analysis already does what you want (and a lot more), but the other profilers are even more useful. Worth the money, if you can afford it.

Comment: I hadn't heard of this tool before.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The link now redirect to smartbear.com. The actual link should now be http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/application-performance-profiling.