# Find unused code

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

I have to refactor a large C# application, and I found a lot of functions that are never used. How can I check for unused code, so I can remove all the unused functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tools and techniques do you use to find dead code in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162641/what-tools-and-techniques-do-you-use-to-find-dead-code-in-net)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool for finding unreferenced functions (dead, obsolete code) in a C# app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585/is-there-a-tool-for-finding-unreferenced-functions-dead-obsolete-code-in-a-c)

Comment: I'm surprised that this is labelled as off topic,  I found the question and answers useful 11 years after the question was written.  the off-topic link provided says that "... software tools commonly used by programmers; and is ..." is definitely relevant for SO!.

Comment: Still usefull 12 years later.

Comment: Still useful 14 years later.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Yes, ReSharper does this. Right click on your solution and selection "Find Code Issues". One of the results is "Unused Symbols". This will show you classes, methods, etc., that aren't used.

Comment: this is great. not enough people know about this. You have to turn on Solution Wide Analysis also to get everything to show up.

Comment: Resharper is a great tool, but I found it to be unreliable for this task. I have a public method where I've removed all references. If I right-click the method and select Show Usages, there are none, but Resharper's code issues doesn't list it as unused.

Comment: On Jarrett Meyer's answer, right-click on "project" instead of "solution" to save search time in a multi-project solution.

Comment: We're using dependency injection.  As a result, everything looks used to resharper because even unused types are still being registered with unity.

Comment: In addition, unit tests hold onto references.

Comment: Unfortunately I also had the same experience as user890155.

Comment: @user890155 That would be because the method is public, the library could be consumed by another application not in the current solution. I believe it will only flag internal and private methods as being code issues if unused.

Comment: @elggarc Regarding dependency injection, take a look at Agent Mulder plugin mentioned here: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/08/resharper-70-plug-ins/

Project homepage: http://hmemcpy.github.com/AgentMulder/

Agent Mulder — support for Dependency Injection frameworks such as Autofac, Castle Windsor, Unity. Since ReSharper doesn’t know about these containers, classes can frequently be marked as unused, or not instantiated. Agent Mulder tells ReSharper when these classes are being used, and provides navigation to the registration point from each class.

Comment: Agent Mulder looks like it will do the trick when running inspections locally. If you're running inspections on a build server, though, you may be out of luck. AFAIK, the ReSharper command line runner used in TeamCity doesn't support plugins.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/01/24/agent-mulder-supporting-ioc-in-resharper/#comment-71446

Comment: This process with screenshots (including how to turn on solution-wide analysis): https://chrisseroka.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/find-unused-private-and-public-methods-with-resharper/

Comment: ReSharper can be a good solution of course. I just have no idea why they have made it so expensive. People have made entire SDKs for much much cheaper prices.

Comment: There are a dozen duplicates of this exact same question that all reference R#, should they all be flagged Advertising at this point?

Comment: The most recent version of resharper doesn't seem to have this "Unused Symbols" any longer. But within the source code, if the function name is grey (not black) indicates it's not used.

Answer (score 30):

It's a great question, but be warned that you're treading in dangerous waters here. When you're deleting code you will have to make sure you're compiling and testing often.

One great tool come to mind:

NDepend - this tool is just amazing. It takes a little while to grok, and after the first 10 minutes I think most developers just say "Screw it!" and delete the app. Once you get a good feel for NDepend, it gives you amazing insight to how your apps are coupled.  Check it out: http://www.ndepend.com/. Most importantly, this tool will allow you to view methods which do not have any direct callers.  It will also show you the inverse, a complete call tree for any method in the assembly (or even between assemblies).

Whatever tool you choose, it's not a task to take lightly.  Especially if you're dealing with public methods on library type assemblies, as you may never know when an app is referencing them.

Comment: Another word of caution, if your app is asp.net, with NDepend you will need to precompile your site so you can analyze the code-behinds and NDepend cannot cover/know about calls from the aspx pages (ie method calls in ObjectDataSources and the like)

Answer (score 17):

Resharper is good for this like others have stated. Be careful though, these tools don't find you code that is used by reflection, e.g. cannot know if some code is NOT used by reflection.

Answer (score 15):

As pointed Jeff the tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) can help to find unused methods, fields and types.

To elaborate a bit, NDepend proposes to write [Code Rule over LINQ Query (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). Around [200 default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed, 3 of them being dedicated to *unused/dead code* detection

Basically such a rule to detect unused method for example looks like:

```
// <Name>Dead Methods</Name>
warnif count > 0 
from m in Application.Methods where !m.MethodsCallingMe.Any()
select m
```

[image: NDepend rule to find unused methods (dead methods)]

But this rule is naive and will return trivial false positives. There are many situations where a method is never called yet it is not unused (entry point, class constructor, finaliser...) this is why the 3 default rules are more elaborated:

- [Potentially dead Types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Types.html) (hence detect unused class, struct, interface, delegate...)
- [Potentially dead Methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Methods.html)
- [Potentially dead Fields](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Fields.html)

NDepend integrates in Visual Studio 2022, 2019, 2017,2015, 2013, 2012, 2010, thus these rules can be [checked/browsed/edited right inside the IDE](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx). The tool can also be integrated into your CI process and it can build [reports](http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports.aspx) that will show rules violated and culprit code elements. NDepend has also a [VS Team Services extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ndepend.ndependextension).

If you click these 3 links above toward the source code of these rules, you'll see that the ones concerning types and methods are a bit complex. This is because they detect not only unused types and methods, but also types and methods used *only* by unused dead types and methods (recursive).

This is *static analysis*, hence the prefix *Potentially* in the rule names. If a code element is used *only* through reflection, these rules might consider it as unused which is not the case.

In addition to using these 3 rules, I'd advise measuring code coverage by tests and striving for having full coverage. Often, you'll see that code that cannot be covered by tests, is actually *unused/dead* code that can be safely discarded. This is especially useful in complex algorithms where it is not clear if a branch of code is reachable or not.

*Disclaimer: I work for NDepend.*

Comment: Hi, how can I delete them quickly using NDepend? I found that this only found them out.

Answer (score 6):

I would also mention that using IOC aka Unity may make these assessments misleading.  I may have erred but several very important classes that are instantiated via Unity appear to have no instantiation as far as ReSharper can tell.  If I followed the ReSharper recommendations I would get hosed!

Answer (score 4):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does a great job of finding unused code.

In the VS IDE, you can right click on the definition and choose 'Find All
References', although this only works at the solution level.

Answer (score 2):

The truth is that the tool can never give you a 100% certain answer, but coverage tool can give you a pretty good run for the money.

If you count with comprehensive unit test suite, than you can use test coverage tool to see exactly what lines of code were not executed during the test run. You will still need to analyze the code manually: either eliminate what you consider dead code or write test to improve test coverage.

One such tool is [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/), with open source precursor on [Sourceforge](http://ncover.sourceforge.net/). Another alternative is [PartCover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/).

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net) on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across AXTools CODESMART..Try that once.
Use code analyzer in reviews section.It will list dead local and global functions along with
other issues.

Answer (score 0):

FXCop is a code analyzer... It does much more than find unused code. I used FXCop for a while, and was so lost in its recommendations that I uninstalled it.

I think NDepend looks like a more likely candidate.