# What can I use for good quality code coverage for C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, code-coverage

I wonder what options there are for .NET (or C# specifically) code coverage, especially in the lower priced segment?

I am not looking for recommendations, but for a comparison of products based on facts. I know the following:

- [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/)

  - Seems to be very popular and looks quite good
  - Supports statement coverage and branch coverage
  - [$480 for "NCover 3 Complete"](https://www.ncover.com/quote)
  - Older beta versions are available [for free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-cnet#276840)
- [Visual Studio (2008 Pro) | (2005 Team System (Development, Test or Team Suite Editions))](https://web.archive.org/web/20090118182937/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/cc149003.aspx)

  - Well, it's Microsoft so I'd expect it to work properly
  - Fully integrated into Visual Studio
  - At least $5,469
- [PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) - no further development (moved to OpenCover)

  - Open source
  - Supports statement coverage
- [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) - successor to PartCover

  - OpenSource
  - Supports branch and statement coverage
  - 32 and 64 bit support
  - Silverlight support
  - [Background](http://scubamunki.blogspot.com/2011/06/opencover-first-beta-release.html)
  - [Tutorial on The Code Project by the primary developer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/677691/Getting-code-coverage-from-your-NET-testing-using)
  - No [.NET Core support yet](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/595)
- [SD Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CSharpTestCoverage.html)

  - Works with 32 and 64 bits, full C# 4.0
  - Handles both small and very large code bases
  - $250 for single user license
- [JetBrains dotCover](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/)

  - $100 for Personal License. Free for user groups, open source projects, students and teachers.
  - Supports statement coverage
  - Silverlight support
- [NCrunch](https://www.ncrunch.net/)

  - $159 for personal license
  - $289 for commercial seat license
      <s>* Free during beta, [to become commercial, pricing unknown](https://blog.ncrunch.net/post/The-Future-Of-NCrunch-Part-2.aspx) [future unknown](https://blog.ncrunch.net/post/The-Future-of-NCrunch.aspx)</s>.
  - Code coverage indicators in Visual Studio
  - Continuous (near real time) testing
  - Visual per-test code coverage
  - Performance metrics, parallel multi-core test execution
- [NDepend](https://www.ndepend.com/Coverage.aspx)

  - [$410](https://www.ndepend.com/Purchase.aspx) for developer license
  - NDepend can import coverage data from NCover, DotCover, Visual Studio 2017; 2015, 2013, 2012, 2010 and 2008 Code Coverage files.
  - Dependency graph
  - Dependency structure matrix
  - Visualizing code metrics
  - Validating code rules

Comment: The question is already duplicated in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/123/tool-for-code-coverage-of-unit-tests-in-c. Can it be migrated & merged?

Comment: I didn't see AxoCover mentioned here, it is free and works quite well IMO: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=axodox1.AxoCover](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=axodox1.AxoCover)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I use the version of NCover that comes with [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net). It will allow you to easily right-click on your unit test class library, and hit *Test With→Coverage*, and it will pull up the report.

Comment: Gotta love TestDriven.NET; as it happens, I use VSTS, but I tend to use NUnit (not MSTes), and use TestDriven.NET to "Test With -> Team Coverage", which uses the MSTest coverage tool (including colorizing) with my NUnit tests. Fantastic.

Comment: This is what I used as well - until I moved my apps into 64bits :-(

Comment: Doesn't work with .NET core yet.

Answer (score 46):

An alternative to NCover can be [PartCover](https://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/), is an open source code coverage tool for .NET very similar to NCover, it includes a console application, a GUI coverage browser, and XSL transforms for use in [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl).

It is a very interesting product.

**[OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover)** has replaced PartCover.

Comment: PartCover has essentially been replaced by OpenCover (https://github.com/sawilde/opencover), as PartCover stagnated with support only for .NET 2.

Answer (score 18):

JetBrains (of [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) fame) has been working on a coverage tool for a little while called [dotCover](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/DCVR/dotCover+Early+Access+Program). It's showing a great deal of promise.

Comment: dotCover is released and available for purchase since Sep 2010: http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/

Comment: dotCover is also part of TeamCity, no additional personal licenses required

Answer (score 15):

I just tested out [NCrunch](https://www.ncrunch.net/) and have to say I am very impressed. It is a continuous testing tool that will add code coverage to your code in Visual Studio at almost real time. At the time as I write this NCrunch is free. It is a little unclear if it going to be free, cost money or be opened source in [the future](https://blog.ncrunch.net/post/The-Future-of-NCrunch.aspx) though.

Comment: Not free as of 3/20/2014

Answer (score 4):

[TestCocoon](http://www.testcocoon.org/index.html) is also pretty nice. It is in active development and has a user community:

- Open source (GPL 3)
- Supports C/C++/C# cross platform (Linux, Windows, and Mac)
- CoverageScanner - Instrumentation during the Generation
- CoverageBrowser - View, Analysis and Management of Code Coverage Result

However, TestCocoon is no longer developed and its creators are now producing a commercial software for C/C++.

Comment: TestCocoon was renamed to [Squish Coco](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/coco/) when the main developer (and TestCocoon) joined [froglogic](http://www.froglogic.com/index.php). the current Squish Coco release also supports C#.

Answer (score 3):

There are pre-release (beta) versions of [NCover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NCover) [available for free](http://www.ncover.com/download/discontinued). They work fine for most cases, especially when combined with NCoverExplorer.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be available anymore...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what the difference is with the retail NCover, but there is also an NCover [project on SourceForge](http://ncover.sourceforge.net/) that is of course open source and free.

Comment: The version on Sourceforge is the basis for the current versions of NCover. It's not being actively worked on/supported anymore but still widely available. They are up to version 3.0 now.

Answer (score 1):

See the [C# Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CSharpTestCoverage.html) tool from my company, Semantic Designs:

It has very low overhead, handles huge systems of files,  intuitive GUI, howing coverage on specific files, and generated report with coverage breakdown at method, class and package levels.

Comment: given this is a commercial product you should really indicate  cost :D

Comment: The price is prominently displayed in the summary of results in the question that started this thread.

Answer (score 1):

[TestMatrix](http://submain.com/testmatrix) is a unit test runner and code coverage tool.

Answer (score 1):

*[C# Test Coverage Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CSharpTestCoverage.html)* has very low overhead, handles huge systems of files, intuitive GUI showing coverage on specific files, and generated report with coverage breakdown at method, class, and package levels.

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage features, as well as programmable API's, come with Visual Studio 2010. Sadly, the only two editions that include the full Code Coverage capabilities are Premium and Ultimate. However, I do believe the API's will be available with any edition, so creating code coverage files and writing a viewer for the coverage info would likely be possible.

Answer (score 0):

We've released EAP to [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover) and will be releasing the beta version soon.