# C# Code Coverage metrics

Tags: c#, code-coverage, metrics

Is there a free commercially available code coverage tool (down to invidual LOC level) available?

I am aware of VS2008 Team Edition, but unfortunatly do not have the budget to perchase a license! So Im looking for a free (as in beer) alternative.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NCover](http://ncover.sourceforge.net/) is an open source code coverage tool for .NET. It appears that newer commercial versions are available too at [NCover.com](http://www.ncover.com/).

Also see this previous question: [Code Coverage for C#/.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net)