# How to Identify any redundant code C#

Tags: c#, class, refactoring, dead-code

I have been given this task:
Identify any redundant code in the classes. Explain in detail why the code is redundant.

I am working with a large scale c# application with dozens of classes, can anyone recommend where to begin or how best to approach this?

Comment: You can try to use Resharper tool to show you some redundant code.

Comment: Install [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/‎)

Comment: Resharper is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use microsoft visual studio for this here is link of it , this feature is part of visual studio 2013 mostly part of Code analyzer.

[Finding Duplicate Code by using Code Clone Detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205279.aspx)

couple of good question sabout code coverage:

[What can I use for good quality Code Coverage for C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net)

[C# Code Coverage metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556399/c-code-coverage-metrics)

Also look at Microsoft's FxCop for static analysis:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx