# What is a good, free C# unit test coverage tool?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, code-coverage

I'm looking for a tool that I can run against my code base to determine which areas of my code are covered by NUnit tests I've written. I would appreciate any suggestions at all, and example usage if needed. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net might help

Comment: I had to dig a little but the sourceforge free NCover helped! Thanks so much! [http://ncover.sourceforge.net/]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I like [NCover](http://www.ncover.com) along with [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net) (for Visual Studio integration).

[PartCover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/) is a good alternative, too. But as far as I know, there is no Visual Studio integration for PartCover.

Comment: Hey thanks! I downloaded PartCover, installed it, and configured it, but I got a ThreadInterrupted exception. The manual pointed to nunit-gui.exe, but I'm running NUnit 2.5. Is there a way to get this error to go away and run it with NUnit 2.5 for my asp.net mvc project? (I can provide full stack trace if it helps)

Answer (score 3):

I use TestDriven.NET at both work and home, works a treat for me :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the input. I took a look, but unfortunately I need something free. It looks like this tool costs money. Am I missing, or not finding a link to the free version? Thanks again!

Comment: Did you look at the Personal License?

Comment: Yes, if it is for personal use I believe it is free?

Comment: I didn't see on, but I'll take another look :) Thanks Sara and Agent_9191!

Comment: Ok I got it, but I can't figure out how this tool reports coverage. Any ideas?

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. Had to use free version of NCover! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please use TestDriven.NET to test.