# How can I measure code coverage for background program?

Tags: c#, code-coverage

My company is developing database software. Most of that is made of C++ and some part is C#.
The part of C# is a library module.
There is a executable file. aaa.exe and windowClient.dll used by aaa.exe.
I want to check the coverage for this windowClient.dll.
Are there any way to do this?

Comment: You can find lots of options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net

Answer (score 0):

When using a coverage tool you can always select the assembly to test for coverage and the executable that should be started.

E.g., OpenCover https://github.com/sawilde/opencover/wiki/Usage

```
opencover -target:aaa.exe -filter:+windowClient.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools available for this some open source and some commercial

Open Source

[OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) - branch and sequence coverage (32/64) Silverlight support - all .NET Languages

[PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) - sequence coverage only - all .NET languages

Commercial

[Semantic Designs](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/index.html) - C# and C++ coverage and many others

[NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) - branch and sequence coverage - I assume all .NET languages only ever used for C# though.

As Olaf has commented there are [a lot of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net)