# Running a ranorex test(rxtst) file through dotcover

Tags: .net, code-coverage, dotcover, ranorex

I need to find a way to automate some UI testing of .NET programs through ranorex and generate a summarized code coverage report in some form. I've been leaning towards using dotcover as the code coverage tool as it seems to be the simplest to automate tests for, being that it can just run an application and check the coverage after completion. Is there any way to generate a code coverage report using a ranorex test file and dotcover, and how? If this isn't possible, are there any suggestions for a tool other than dotcover capable of doing this? Preferably the application will be able to run on its own, without Visual Studio, but if it needs Visual Studio that's fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) on the command line then you need to create a file with all your arguments in it, follow [these instructions](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/07/running-code-coverage-from-the-console-with-dotcover/). You will need to supply it with the the files/commands to run [ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/) - see [ranorex command line options](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/lesson-4-ranorex-test-suite.html#c3581)

As it seems you can run [ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/) on the command line then there are plenty of alternatives to [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) available see [What can I use for good quality Code Coverage for C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net)

My personal favourite is [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) (for obvious reasons) but I have also used [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/), [PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) and [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) to good effect in commercial environments.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer helped please mark the question as answered.