# VS2010: Code coverage for c++ DLL (/clr)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, clr, code-coverage

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243171(v=vs.100).aspx) project which has been compiled with */clr* and */clr:pure* options doesn't support unit testing.

However, I can create unit test project and use it for testing */clr* and */clr:pure* project. But ***code coverage*** is not supported at this time.

How can I determine code coverage for C++ project which compiled into DLL with */clr* option?

Answer (score 0):

If it is CLR i.e. compiled to .NET IL under the hood, then you should be able to use most of .NET code-coverage tools, see [What can I use for good quality Code Coverage for C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net) for a master list of .NET code-Coverage tools.

Any tool that uses the profiler API, such as [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) (free) or [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) (commercial) should have no trouble as they work against the IL and use the PDBs - I can't vouch for the others but I don't see any obvious reasons as to why not.