# VS 2012 Code Coverage

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

We are using VS2008 prof. in our application. In 2008 prof. code coverage feature isn’t available. So we are achieving this by creating unit test project and added its entry in .vsmdi file and running test cases we can get code coverage feature.

Now we are planning to migrate our application from VS2008 prof. to VS2012 prof. In VS2012 prof. also code coverage feature isn’t available. So we also trying the same VS2008 prof. approach to achieve it but still I am not getting code coverage option.

Please let me know if there is any way to achieve code coverage feature in VS2012.

Comment: Hint: you can deactivate caps lock by pressing <kbd>caps lock</kbd> again ;)

Answer (score 1):

Code Coverage is native only available in VS12 Premium and Ultimate not in Profesional. See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare) at *"Determine how much code is being tested with code coverage analysis"*.

Answer (score 1):

There are other alternatives that you can use to get code coverage (assuming you are using .NET) see [What can I use for good quality Code Coverage for C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net).

I am partial to [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) for obvious reasons :)