# Mark method as covered by unit testing?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I am currently writing unit tests for some of my methods and I still have a lot to write.
Is there a way to mark methods in my primary project as covered or handled by unit tests?

I would like to have some overview.

Comment: You should consider getting a tool for code coverage, this will not only tell you which methods you have covered, but also which parts of those methods you have covered. The two tools I use are NCrunch and dotCover but there are many available. If I'm not mistaken, Visual Studio also has built in some support for this. The best tools integrate into Visual Studio in such a way that you can view in the code editor itself the status of code coverage for a line.

Comment: Here is another question that lists a lot of tools as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Those comments should be an answer :)