# How to run tests showing code coverage in Visual Studio for Mac COMMUNITY 8.3.4

Tags: code-coverage, visual-studio-mac

I'm new in C# after a brief use of it in 2010.

I'm asking an Internet search engine - one claiming not to track me - how to "visual studio for mac show tests coverage".

That would link me to [Use code coverage to determine how much code is being tested](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2019).

I think that's no use to me, because they command to:

> 1. On the **Test** menu, select **Analyze Code Coverage for All Tests**.

I don't have such a menu to begin with.

This is `Visual Studio for Mac COMMUNITY 8.3.4`.

How to?

---

[I asked Apple SE before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373536/), however unsuccessful to get any meaningful answer. I should have guessed that properly, shame on me.

Comment: There is no built-in support for code coverage in Visual Studio for Mac. There is an old command line tool [monocov](https://github.com/mono/monocov) which may or may not work. If you are using .NET Core then [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet) will allow you to check coverage for tests from the command line.

Comment: Now thats' a useful answer enabling me to forward a derived question to software recommendations. Thank you.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/70325/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32118808/4739420