# Is there a way to find all unused code in a .NET project using ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, automated-refactoring

I've just done a major, major overhaul on a colleagues project and throughout the process almost everything got rewritten. There was far too much code beforehand.

Now, I am left with the prospect that in amongst my project somewhere are old pre-refactoring methods that are no longer needed.

Is there a way to search the **whole project** for such methods in one go?

I understand the risk of potentially removing code used via reflection.

It's very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245963/find-unused-code), except I would like two extra things:

- An answer specific to ReSharper
- Instructions on how to achieve this using ReSharper as I cannot seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not way to do this with R# for the entire solution/project. The only way I know of is to go through your code manually, pressing Alt+F7 on each method name.

Answer (score 8):

Use **solution-wide** analysis.

If you change "Unused declaration" in
"**R# Options/Inspection Severity/Code Redundancies/Unused declaration**" to "**Show as Errors**", you'll be able to identify all unused declarations.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. This will show you unused declarations with private visibility, but not with internal or public. ReSharper 5 will likely have better story about this issue.

Comment: This now works for public and internal members in the beta of R# 5.