# Identifying unused classes / controls / pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, refactoring

We have a 10+ years old ASP.NET website project, with lots of unused / legacy user controls and pages.

Is there a tool which can assist in the process of identifying these elements of the solution, so we could refactor them out?

I know the issue is complicated because not all types are referenced as types which a compiler / tool might recognize. e.g. objects instantiated by reflection are instantiated using a string representing the class name. In addition asp.net pages are generally not referenced as types, but as page identifier strings in markup.

It still seems like someone would have created a tool which handles these cases and creates a candidate list of unused classes / pages / user controls

Comment: what about using resharper it will find unused methods  in .cs page also...

Comment: Resharper is good at finding unused methods, but not at identifing pages and controls that are unused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to find unused registered controls

```
<%@\s*Register\s+TagPrefix\s*=\s*"(?<tagprefix>[^"]+)"\s+TagName\s*=\s*"(?<tagname>[^"]+)"\s+Src\s*=\s*"[^"]+"\s*%>(?!.*?\k<tagprefix>:\k<tagname>\s+)
```

I used [powergrep](http://www.powergrep.com/) to run this regex. 
The "Dot matches newline" checkbox should be enabled to work properly.

Comment: Looks interesting. Can you describe what it does?

Comment: Sure. The first part looks for controls registration template <%@ Register TagPrefix="Myprefix" TagName="Mytag" Src="~/mypath.ascx" %>   and collects tagprefix tagname in the named groups **(?<groupname>blabla>)**.  The second part of regex uses negative lookahead **(?!blabla)**   So we can read this regex as: please find all controls registration that are not used later in the text.  Our project is also 10+ years old :)

Comment: I used SublimeText to execute this.  I had to add an inline flag to the very beginning of the regex to dot-match newlines: `(?s)`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992596/regex-in-sublime-text-match-any-character-including-newlines

Answer (score 2):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is a refactoring tool which might help you to identify clouds of unused classes and methods. It can also delete them safely. It allows you to delete a method or class and adjust all it's usages. See: [Safe delete](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Refactoring/safeDelete.html)

It has also appropriate support of ASP.NET. See: [ASP.NET support](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/asp_net_editor.html)

Comment: Thanks - we already use Resharper, but I don't think it can identify unused pages and user controls.

Comment: Have you tried [find usages](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages.html) functionality. I am sure you can use it to find at least unused user controls.

Comment: yes - this is ok for individual namespaces, and methods, types on a manual case-by-case basis, but I'm hoping to find a tool which can generate a solution wide report

Comment: ok. you can do it also using Resharper see Q&A [Find unused code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245963/find-unused-code)