# RegEx in Sublime Text: Match any character, including newlines?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

Is there a way to match any character in Sublime Text, including newlines? I saw that Sublime uses Boost's syntax but that the `.` character won't match newlines without a specific flag set.

Comment: I think it's more correct to quote the documentation...
Sublime Text uses the Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) engine from the Boost library. http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Try adding the `(?s)` inline flag start the start of the pattern. That will make `.` match *any* character.

Comment: As an example: `<font([\s\S]*?)>` matches the `font` start tag, even if the tag spans several lines.

Comment: So does `<font((?s).*?)>` and `(?s)<font(.*?)>`.