# Finding Reference to Class & Methods

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I am trying to find out all the classes and assemblies which are using/referencing a particular class. Is there any way to find out through programming in C#?

For example, if `Class1` is called/referenced by `Class2` in `Assembly1`, `Class3` in `Assembly2`, I want to find `Class2` & `Class3` using C# programming.

Is there anyone who could help me? Is there any tool that could help in this? I want to write a small program to read class from one assembly and find the classes where that particular class is referenced/used.

My question in short: **How to find unused class or method in my codebase by writing a C# program as a part of code cleanup activity?**

Comment: Is it in compile-time or run-time?

Comment: "This tag is for assembly language programming questions not specific to any one processor." -- please use the [.net-assembly] tag instead

Comment: If runtime, it is possible through reflection, but you will have to enumerate through all assemblies, all their classes, all methods, properties and constructors and their parameters etc. of the classes and then you will still not catch references only used within the code body of the methods etc.

Comment: Do you need to find the assmembly that only exists on one machine which was used to do a bit of trivial coding 6 months ago, and has since been switched off? Or just within the current AppDomain?

Comment: now the question is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245963/find-unused-code

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a tool to do this, you could use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) which can  do what you're describing and also a lot more.

<strike>Or, if you're using ReSharper: Right-Click, "find usages"...</strike> (not useful for finding unused code indeed)

Comment: Talk about time consuming to do that on every class/method since he want to find unused classes/methods for code clean up.

Comment: Then use NDepend. It is the perfect tool for doing this. "Find dead code" is a main feature.

Comment: Thanks noah for the quick help.