# Check unused code in web application in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, optimization

is there a way (or a free plug-in) to check the never used code (in VB.NET in my case) in a ASP.NET web application (a web project, 2 class library and a web service)?

Thank you in advance.

Luis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find unused code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245963/find-unused-code)

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper tool is having this capability to filter never used code. Refer [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Introduction__Index.html) article. follow below steps after plugged this tool:

1. Right click on your solution
2. Select "Find Code Issues".

Results should have an option "Unused Symbols".

it refers all classes and methods that are never used.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try with the Trial version of ReSharper.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I've got these results, but there is no voice "Unused Symbols".

What do you think?