# In Visual Studio 2008 is there a way to find all references that have no references for all methods not just 1 at a time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I know you can right click on an individual method and find all references for a single method but is there a way to find all references where there is only the method definition returned (i.e. no external references to the method).

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245963/find-unused-code   and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162641/what-tools-and-techniques-do-you-use-to-find-dead-code-in-net  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585/is-there-a-tool-for-finding-unreferenced-functions-dead-obsolete-code-in-a-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: Find unused code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413548/visual-studio-find-unused-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard Visual Studio install there is no built-in command that will do this.  However there are other tools out there that have this functionality.  Most notably is [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)

Comment: Is there an open source or free version of a similar tool?