# Is there a way to check if all defined functions are called?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

Is there a way to figure out if every function defined in code is called somewhere?

I have been doing a major code update to a large project of mine and I want to make sure the old functions that are no longer used are removed from the code.

Is there a better way then searching for each function in the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool for finding unreferenced functions (dead, obsolete code) in a C# app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585/is-there-a-tool-for-finding-unreferenced-functions-dead-obsolete-code-in-a-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mark each method you are trying to remove as [Obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.iserror.aspx) with `IsError` set to `true`.
When you mark a method as such, you will get a compilation error and will be able to find out if you can *safely* remove the method.

```
    [Obsolete("Don't use this method", /* IsError */ true)]
    public void Foo () {}
```

Comment: I tend to turn on IsError for my own internal libs. For other cases, I leaeve it off

Comment: I do that too. And often leave them like that for a while, until I am absolutely certain I don't need them anymore. Unless I really am absolutely certain I don't need it anymore already of course :p

Comment: @Svish: Turning on IsError seems to be obtrusive sometimes but sometimes when it's gotta go, it's gotta go.

Answer (score 2):

[FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476.aspx) should be able to find orphaned/unused methods.  I think static analysis is what you're looking for, not code coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that will catch everything but reflection.

1. Delete the method
2. Compile

This seems a bit overkill but it has the advantage that you can "batch" queries by deleting multiple functions.

Comment: Order could matter here, though? If A() calls B() but nothing calls A(), deleting B() first will be misleading since it won't compile.

Comment: @Andrew I didn't say it was easy :).

Comment: @JaredPar: I think, I have read about that process from "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" by Michael Feathers on how to refactor legacy code with no tests.

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage tool like NCover?

EDIT:
This assumes you have sufficient tests for functionality and are determined to get rid of every unnecessary function. Delete-then-compile would work but isn't scalable.. regardless, the point is that you're going to want some kind of source analysis tool (either static or runtime analysis).

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

- Depending on your development tools, you may be able to generate warnings for functions that are declared but never called.
- You may be able to generate a linker map, then compare its list of functions with a list you generate (with `grep` or `ctags`?) directly from your source.