# Tool to find all unused Code

Tags: c#, static-analysis

I need a tool I can run that will show me a list of unused methods, variables, properties, and classes.  CSS classes would be an added bonus.

I heard FXCop can do this?  or NDepend or something?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate since you want CSS too, but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585/is-there-a-tool-for-finding-unreferenced-functions-dead-obsolete-code-in-a-c

Comment: And I don't want to have it change things across the board. Basically I want a list of possible issues where I can pick one by one. I can't just go fixing the entire application, my boss would kill me

Comment: I would like to know if NDepend gives you a nice list first before you apply any changes to code via code analysis.  Anyone know off the top of their head that uses it?

Comment: NDepend makes no changes, it just provides data.

Comment: This was asked over a year and a half ago.

Answer (score 20):

Look at [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Comment: +1 Definitely R#, and see their function "Code cleanup" for finding all unused code.

Comment: When you're editing in R# all grayed-out methods/fields/properties are unused.

Comment: does code cleanup automatically change the files without your permission or does it give a nice list first?

Comment: well, I've got a color scheme that might override this.  I don't see greyed out methods and I am using R#

Comment: Coffeeaddict - Code Cleanup only performs **non-breaking** changes. It will not delete any unused methods or otherwise, but it will delete extra using statements, fix formatting, convert to auto properties and more. This is all customizable, but no, it doesn't confirm before it performs tasks, however, it doesn't save automatically so you can always undo things.

Comment: yea, I don't want to have it change things across the board.  Basically I want a list of possible issues where I can pick one by one.  I can't just go fixing the entire application, my boss would kill me.

Comment: You can always perform "cleanup" on a single file at a time.

Answer (score 8):

[Code Analysis in VSTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182023%28VS.80%29.aspx) will generate warnings about this during the build process. You can set it up to treat Warnings As Errors.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to find unused code and [Dust-Me Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) to find unused CSS.

Answer (score 5):

The tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) can help find unused code in a .NET code base. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of this tool.*

NDepend proposes to write [Code Rule over LINQ Query (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). Around [200 default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed, 3 of them being dedicated to *unused/dead code* detection:

- [Potentially dead Types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Types.html) (hence detect unused class, struct, interface, delegate...)
- [Potentially dead Methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Methods.html) (hence detect unused method, ctor, property getter/setter...)
- [Potentially dead Fields](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Fields.html)

NDepend is integrated in Visual Studio, thus these rules can be [checked/browsed/edited right inside the IDE](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx). The tool can also be integrated into your CI process and it can build [reports](http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports.aspx) that will show rules violated and culprit code elements.

If you click these 3 links above toward the source code of these rules, you'll see that the ones concerning types and methods are a bit complex. This is because they detect not only unused types and methods, but also types and methods used *only* by unused dead types and methods (recursive).

This is *static analysis*, hence the prefix *Potentially* in the rule names. If a code element is used *only* through reflection, these rules might consider it as unused which is not the case.

In addition to using these 3 rules, I'd advise measuring code coverage by tests and striving for having full coverage. Often, you'll see that code that cannot be covered by tests, is actually *unused/dead* code that can be safely discarded. This is especially useful in complex algorithms where it is not clear if a branch of code is reachable or not.

Answer (score 2):

[Gendarme](http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme) has also different rules to find unused code.

Comment: I'd never heard of this one before, so I thought I'd give it a download... It looks pretty nice!

Comment: I've used Gendarme.  It's great at finding unused *variables*, but doesn't really help with unused methods or classes.