# Blocks of code that can never be reached

Tags: .net, profiling, code-analysis

I have a .NET project (C#), where in my code there's a function like this:

```
public void myFunction(string myStr)
{
   myStr = "This is not an empty string";

   if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStr))
   {
       DoSomething();
   }
}
```

I want to analyze my application to see if there are blocks of code that can never be reached. How could I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/65585/419436 ?

Comment: doesn't VS2010 underline when a piece of code is unreachable?

Comment: @AdamSweeney only if it is explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to make your code more efficient.
Checking of unavailable code areas in one of it's features.

Comment: Does this handle OP's example?

Comment: Just checked code given in topic, was suprized, but resharper was silent, and no warning given. Though still it remains most useful tool for code quality for me.

Comment: So, I understand resharper is generally useful to you, but why does that make resharper the answer to OPs question?

Comment: Cuz main question was "I want to analyze my application to see if there are blocks of code that can never be reached. How could I do this?" If resharpers isn't useful in one case, that doesn't make in bad tool for whole application examination. That's not an adv.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in general, you need a symbolic analysis of the values along all control paths, and boolean symbolic simplification to determine if the condition is true.  For example:

```
void bar(...a) {
  ...
  x=2*a;
  if (...)  x=17;
  foo(x)
  ...
}
void foo(int x) {
  if (x<a && !x>5) { // dead code if called from bar ...
  ...
```

To know that the dead code line is really dead,  you have to find *all* calls
to foo and verify that each one causes this condition to occur.  So you need
a global call graph, for which you need global function pointer analysis, for
which you need global and thus local points-to analysis...

I don't know any off-the-shelf tools that do this.

One could be built with some effort with a program transformation system.  Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) has all of the mentioned machinery available for C.
While all this machinery isn't yet available for C#, it is implemented in largely a langauge agnostic way so getting there for C# is sweat but not impractical.

Answer (score -1):

you may want to use tools like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which can do code quality analysis while developing. it gives you warnings like "code is heuristically unreachable"