# Only keep used types and remove unused types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper, ndepend

Is there any way to remove unused types/code from a project.
lets say I'm using `NAudio`(source code) in my console application and I'm only using the `WaveIn` class from it. Is there any way for me to remove unused classes from the code and only keep the `WaveIn` class and the classes `WaveIn` depends upon? Something down the line of tree shaking

Comment: You mean remove it from a compiled assembly? Not without recompiling the assembly.

Comment: Why do you feel a need to do this, what problem are you hoping to solve?

Comment: No I mean from the source code

Comment: I need to reduce the size of the compiled exe

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question well enough, my bad, early monday not enough coffee. I don't know of any such tool other than *perhaps* ReSharper which will flag a class as unused but it may not actually give you any help here since presumably there are many classes that uses each other, it's just that *your program* does not use them.

Comment: yes that is the exact problem I'm having

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a tool for finding unreferenced functions (dead, obsolete code) in a C# app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585/is-there-a-tool-for-finding-unreferenced-functions-dead-obsolete-code-in-a-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ndepend was the answer

```
from t in Types 
let depth0 = t.DepthOfIsUsedBy("NAudioTrim.Program")
where depth0  >= 0 orderby depth0
select new { t, depth0 }
```

where `NAudioTrim.Program` contains the entry point of my application and contains the used types.
Once you get the list of all used types and the types they use you can delete the rest of the files/types

Comment: What is Types in this case? You you map from Type to IUsed interface required by DepthOfIsUsedBy method