# Is there an quick way to eliminate unused types in a C program in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have a large body of C code (dozens of files that are several thousand lines each) that I'm trying to port from another platform to MSVC++. There are many redundant types in a file because of sloppiness of previous programmers.

Obviously I can eliminate the types one by one and see if they build. Is there a quick way in Visual Studio that I can identify or refactor out unused types?

```
typedef struct {
    int Field1;
    int Field2;
} notused1;

struct notused2 {
    int Field1;
    int Field2;
};

int ActualWork() {
    // Doesn't use either struct
}
```

I don't believe this question is a duplicate of [2380153](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380153/finding-dead-code-in-a-large-c-legacy-application) because that question was asked in 2010.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding "dead code" in a large C++ legacy application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380153/finding-dead-code-in-a-large-c-legacy-application)

Comment: Despite your protestations that a question asked in 2010 is not relevant to you, the situation has not changed significantly in the last 9 years or so, or for the 20-odd years before that.  There isn't a simple automatic way to do it.  There are static analyzers of greater or lesser excellence that may or may not be useful, but the process is still exasperating and not far removed from 'hit or miss'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822663/only-keep-used-types-and-remove-unused-types - this may be closer to your case, please share your feedback if you decide to use code-cleaning tools with Visual Studio

Comment: Does this work for C? This looks like managed code.

Comment: This looks promising: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/?fromMenu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you can deprecate all the symbols and get warnings for each used symbol. 
Then remove all deprecation off from used symbols, and the rest are not used.

like this:

```
#pragma deprecated(X)
struct X {  // will result C4995 warning in visual studio when using this struct
};
```

You can also use `__declspec(deprecated)` 
like this:

```
struct __declspec(deprecated) X {

};
```

[look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/deprecated-c-cpp?view=vs-2017) [and here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/deprecated-cpp?view=vs-2017)

Comment: This is a pretty creative solution in my opinion :)

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer, because it is a visual studio solution, and while its manual its very light touch. Thank you!

Comment: For anyone in the future I've also found the clang program can generate an AST tree of a C program with -ast-dump. This output can then be parsed to build a representation of the program, which can be used for static analysis. Many more steps but something that can go into the long term toolkit